# How to define launchUrl in IIS Express config file

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express

I have created a basic .NET Core 3 API app with the default settings. It has only one controller called "WeatherForecastController". In the "launchSettings.json", the launchUrl setting was set to "weatherforecast" under "IIS Express" profile. By clicking on the run button in Visual Studio, I can easily run the project.

But I wanted to run the app via IIS commandline, so what I did was running the below in cmd.exe

```
iisexpress.exe /config:C:\Users\User\source\repos\SingleExecWebApp\.vs\SingleExecWebApp\config\applicationhost.config /site:SingleExecWebApp
```

The app runs, and I got the following error

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure
```

The IIS console emits the following info

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:61517/" for site "SingleExecWebApp" application "/"
Successfully registered URL "https://localhost:44325/" for site "SingleExecWebApp" application "/"
Registration completed for site "SingleExecWebApp"
IIS Express is running.
Enter 'Q' to stop IIS Express
```

I think what I am missing is the previously mentioned "launchUrl". Am I correct? if yes, how to set it in the above command I ran in cmd.exe. If no, what I am I missing?

Comment: Call `dotnet publish` first, and run from the generated folder. Your source folder is in general invalid for IIS Express/IIS to host without tricks.

Comment: What are those "tricks"

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3